# C# unique file naming with String from Streamreader

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader, streamwriter, visual-studio-2015

ok i have solved my problem of finding a unique word within the file that is then used as the newly created .txt file name.

for example: current.txt files have 200 lines of words/data per file but one of the words is unique("92222225") with every current.txt file.
so the newly created output files from streamwriter becomes 92222225.txt, 933333334.txt and so on.

the whole time i though what i needed was within streamreader or streamwriter.
but what i need to add to the two was "Regex.Match".

here is the code i figured out to use for pulling strings out of a .txt file to use as a name for the output files. also to add other words to the new output file.

```
string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\reporting";
foreach (string txtName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mydocpath, "*.txt"))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtName);

                string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sb.AppendLine(txtName.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine("= = = = = =");
                sb.Append(content);
                if (content.Contains("helloworld"))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine();
                    sb.AppendLine("byeworld");
                }
               sb.AppendLine();
                 sb.AppendLine();
                //string fileName = content.Contains("helloworld").ToString();
                string FindMatch = content;
                Match match = Regex.Match(FindMatch, @"9(([A-Za-z0-9\-])\d+)");

                if (match.Success)
                { 
                     //this is what adds unique word as 922225.txt file name.
                    string capture = match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
                    using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\" + capture + ".txt"))
                    {
                        outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
                    }
                }
       }
```

i updated this whole post so if anyone else may need this.

never even used Regex.Match before, nor knew about it or maybe i forgot about it.

Comment: what's wrong with just replacing `@"\new.txt"` in `new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\new.txt")` with desired filename?

Comment: Your question is not really clear but did you mean `using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(mydocpath, @"901232lOi.txt")))` ?

Comment: thats not what im looking for.

Comment: I think you need to provide a sample of the text you're reading. Is this unique string at the beginning? On a specific line?

Comment: ok i have added a sample of text im reading from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to name your output file use:

```
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\901232lOi.txt"))
```

Comment: this will not help because every new file will have the same name.

Comment: i need streamreader to find string with in the .txt file and use that string as the .txt name.

Comment: you look different strings everytime and when you find them it will be the .txt filename. So you have to find an algorithm that finds your unique string. I think you have to focus finding the string. then we can arrange your code together to name it by using unique string.